# how to develop bootstrap non responsive template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

how to develop bootstrap non responsive template.
How to  create non responsive bootstrap template.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/

Answer (score 0):

Hi there and welcome to stack overflow.

Unfortunately we are not here to write code for you, but help you edit yours and point you in the right direction. There are a plethora of resources for learning how to use bootstrap online. Why don't you go use google, read and come back when you have some specific questions .

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

let me give you a brief intro and later on you can get detailed info from official site. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

1st you need to include bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap.min.js and jquery-1.11.1.min.js in to your html code so that you can use them in order to make responsive templates

2nd make use of navigation classes for showing responsive menus

3rd choose whether you want to make fluid layout (strech view) or grid layout (in terms of rows / columns)

rest of details you can see by yourself in above mentioned link

Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to disable page responsiveness**

1. Omit the viewport  mentioned in the CSS docs
2. Override the
   width on the .container for each grid tier with a single width, for
   example width: 970px !important; Be sure that this comes after the
   default Bootstrap CSS. You can optionally avoid the !important with
   media queries or some selector-fu.
3. If using navbars, remove all
   navbar collapsing and expanding behavior.
4. For grid layouts, use
   .col-xs-* classes in addition to, or in place of, the medium/large
   ones. Don't worry, the extra-small device grid scales to all
   resolutions.